# Permgen error - when Spring SAML changes are added

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

The application that I am working on is authenticated using database. The test environment version of the application didnt encounter any permgen or out of memory error till now.

But there are few customers who are authenticated with their identity providers. To implement this requirement, we have implemented SAML based SSO using SPring-SAML. When the changes are moved to the testing environment, we are encountering Permgen or out of memory errors now and then. Because of which we have to restart the server very frequently.

@vschafer Can you please let me know if this is due to the Spring-SAML implementation for SSO?

Comment: I'd suggest you analyze the heap-dump, eventually your permgen space and identify objects which are leaking the memory.

Comment: Did you find which objects are leaking? Can you share your heap dump?